# Table caption for data frame paged printing in bookdown::html_document2

Tags: r, dataframe, r-markdown, bookdown

I am using the `bookdown::html_document2` output format to render a [single document](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/a-single-document.html) for automatic numbering of figures/tables/equations, and cross-referencing figures/tables/equations/sections.

Is there a way to get table caption for data frames that are [printed using paged printing](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#data-frame-printing). For instance:

````
---
title: "Use caption with df_print set to page"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
    df_print: paged
---

```{r}
knitr::kable(mtcars, caption = "mtcars caption")
```

```{r}
# Is there an option for a caption?
mtcars
```
````

With the `knitr::kable`, there is the caption argument that I can use and this will appear in the HTML file automatically numbered. But it's not clear to me whether this possible with paged printing?